# Combine Jms messages in one xml structure using WSO2 ESB

Tags: xml, jms, wso2, wso2-esb

I have different xml messages on JMS Queue. Each message has reference document id field in it. Now I want if two messages have same reference document id then it will make one xml response and vice versa.

like xml:

message-1

```
<Root>
<record>
<refdocumentId>123</refdocumentId>
<name>abc</name>
</record>
</Root>
```

message-2

```
<Root>
<record>
<refdocumentId>123</refdocumentId>
<name>xyz</name>
</record>
</Root>
```

messge-3

```
<Root>
<record>
<refdocumentId>222</refdocumentId>
<name>abc</name>
</record>
</Root>
```

Output in WSO2 ESB should be like:

for same reference document id (single message)

```
<Root>
    <record>
    <refdocumentId>123</refdocumentId>
    <name>abc</name>
    </record>
<record>
    <refdocumentId>123</refdocumentId>
    <name>xyz</name>
    </record>
    </Root>
```

For different reference document id:

```
<Root>
    <record>
    <refdocumentId>222</refdocumentId>
    <name>abc</name>
    </record>
    </Root>
```

How can we achieve this scenario in WSO2 ESB. Any help would be great appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is, have a custom class mediator , where keep a list and store ref IDs. whenever new message hits ESB, check for the ID and build required message